# Unable to Cast a String to Integer IN JSP

Tags: jsp, nullpointerexception, numberformatexception

I am getting value as:

```
String responseTime = request.getParameter("rt");
```

where `rt` is name of the textbox.

I want the Integer/Float value of `responseTime`. But when I write the following code:

```
int rTime = Integer.parseInt(responseTime);
```

or

```
int rTime = Integer.parseInt(responseTime.toString());
```

I get either of these errors

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException;
java.lang.NullPointerException;
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: can you try to print `responseTime` first to make sure it can be parsed into integer?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `responseTime` variable is null. So in first case

```
int rTime = Integer.parseInt(responseTime);
```

you get `NumberFormatException`, because null can not be parsed to an integer.

And for the second case

```
int rTime = Integer.parseInt(responseTime.toString());
```

you get NPE because you call `toString` on null.

So make sure you are passing the variable properly and double check the name of the variable in request.

Comment: I actually tired to invoke an action when submit button is clicked..And I wrote the code for this action in the same jsp page..But when i get the action done in another JSP page it is working!!Y does it happen so?????
And, Tanx All

Comment: @renu sorry but I didn't get you, what you are trying to say? Do you mean you want to call same JSP page on submitting a form? If yes then it will not work when you first load the page. As when you first load the page there will be no "rt" variable in request.